# How to bypass the 'OS Edition Selection' page in a Windows unattended setup?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, unattended, adk

I've generated an `AutoUnattend.xml` file using Windows System Image Manager, included in the ADK, to install Windows 8.1 in an unattended way.

I would like to add an attribute in my `AutoUnattend.xml` file to automatically select the OS Edition I want to install, bypassing the OS selection screen.

**`AutoUnattend.xml`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <servicing>
    <package action="configure">
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package" version="6.3.9600.16384" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="es-ES" />
    </package>
  </servicing>
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
      <UILanguageFallback>es-ES</UILanguageFallback>
      <UILanguage>es-ES</UILanguage>
      <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
      <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Display>
        <HorizontalResolution>1920</HorizontalResolution>
        <VerticalResolution>1080</VerticalResolution>
        <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
      </Display>
      <UserData>
        <ProductKey>
          <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
          <Key>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</Key>
        </ProductKey>
        <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
        <Organization>Elektro Studios</Organization>
        <FullName>MY NAME</FullName>
      </UserData>
      <EnableNetwork>true</EnableNetwork>
      <EnableFirewall>true</EnableFirewall>
      <Restart>Restart</Restart>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <AutoLogon>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <LogonCount>1</LogonCount>
        <Username>Administrator</Username>
      </AutoLogon>
      <ComputerName>Elektro-PC</ComputerName>
      <ProductKey>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</ProductKey>
      <RegisteredOrganization>Elektro Studios</RegisteredOrganization>
      <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
      <WindowsFeatures>
        <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
        <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
        <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
      </WindowsFeatures>
      <Themes>
        <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
      </Themes>
      <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
      <BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>false</BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-HelpAndSupport" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <HelpAndSupport>
        <Manufacturer>Elektro Studios</Manufacturer>
      </HelpAndSupport>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
      <UILanguageFallback>es-ES</UILanguageFallback>
      <UILanguage>es-ES</UILanguage>
      <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
      <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <OOBE>
        <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
        <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
        <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
        <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
        <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
        <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
        <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
        <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
        <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
      </OOBE>
      <VisualEffects>
        <FontSmoothing>On</FontSmoothing>
        <SystemDefaultBackgroundColor>0</SystemDefaultBackgroundColor>
      </VisualEffects>
      <TimeZone>Romance Standard Time</TimeZone>
      <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
      <BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>false</BluetoothTaskbarIconEnabled>
      <Themes>
        <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
      </Themes>
      <WindowsFeatures>
        <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
        <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
        <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
      </WindowsFeatures>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <InputLocale>es-ES</InputLocale>
      <SystemLocale>es-ES</SystemLocale>
      <UILanguage>es-ES</UILanguage>
      <UILanguageFallback>es-ES</UILanguageFallback>
      <UserLocale>es-ES</UserLocale>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="auditSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Themes>
        <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
      </Themes>
      <WindowsFeatures>
        <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
        <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
        <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
      </WindowsFeatures>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="auditUser">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Themes>
        <WindowColor>0</WindowColor>
      </Themes>
      <WindowsFeatures>
        <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
        <ShowInternetExplorer>false</ShowInternetExplorer>
        <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
      </WindowsFeatures>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/administrador/desktop/win%208%20.1/win/sources/install.wim#Windows 8.1" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

- This is the screen I would like to bypass by automatically selecting the unique Windows edition existing in the image [Windows 8.1 Core edition]:
  [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Anyways thanks for notice it, I've hide it for don't promove piracy.

Comment: Using a generic license isn't piracy.  You still have to eventually supply a working valid license.  The generic license is design to be used in this manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a solution [here](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/07/27/windows-8-automated-install-settings/#disabling-the-select-operating-system-dialog)

[image]

[image]

PS: Changed the value to `Windows 8.1` and worked fine!

Answer (score 8):

For Windows 10, I was unable to use `/IMAGE/NAME` and the string value `Windows 10 Pro` (for reasons unknown to me), as proposed in the answer by @ElektroStudios.

This is what I added to my `AutoUnattend.xml` under the `OSImage` tag, which worked for me:

```xml
<InstallFrom>
  <MetaData wcm:action="add">
    <Key>/image/index</Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </MetaData>
</InstallFrom>
```

This automatically selected the first option, as I have two options during an attended installation:

```
Windows 10 Pro   x64  10/30/2015
Windows 10 Home  x64  10/30/2015
```

Comment: +1 For pointing this, this is True, I had the same problem for Windows 10 and solved in the same way using a image index instead of a image name.

Comment: I'm trying this with Win7 and 10. It works great with Win7 but the Win10 (education) version didn't work with "/image/index". It worked with "/image/name" however. Any thoughts?

Comment: They start counting with 1?!

Comment: Name works fine with Windows 10 21H1 (Pro).

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `/image/index` and `/image/name` are case sensitive; in the case of Windows 10 Enterprise v1709:

```xml
<InstallFrom>
  <MetaData wcm:action="add">
    <Key>/IMAGE/INDEX</Key>
    <Value>3</Value>
  </MetaData>
</InstallFrom>
```

If you want to check what values you need, the `imagex` command-line tool that is part of the AIK (Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment) can be used.

Comment: `ImageX` only works on Windows <=7, with [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) being used on Windows >=8.  The AIK is for Windows <=7, with Windows >=8 using the [ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install).

Comment: need more instructions

Answer (score 2):

Using the image name instead of the index:

```xml
<InstallFrom>
  <MetaData wcm:action="add">
    <Key>/IMAGE/NAME</Key>
    <Value>Windows 10 Enterprise</Value>
  </MetaData>
</InstallFrom>
```

Comment: In case anyone wonders, it should be put under `<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" ...>` / `<ImageInstall>` / `<OSImage>`